# How to configure side menu in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

i'm using rails admin and the sidemenu i'd like to tweak into sections. Following the docu, the section can be done with a navigation label on a model and the subs with a parent relation.
however i want the fist level (navigation label) without a model but free text and create subs below.
any tips how to do so?

Comment: have you tried passing a simple string as a parent? `parent 'Parent Label'`

Comment: Didn't work I'm currently using this  
config.model 'Currency' do
      navigation_label 'Reference tables'
end
but now the Currency is under reference tables and all objects with parent: 'Currency' are indented.

Would love to have option to just create a group in navigate and put objects below